# What is the difference between external email encryption and SSL/TLS?

Tags: email, encryption

I understand what SSL/TLS is and basics of how it works. Almost always when I'm sending or receiving email, there is a padlock icon indicating that email was encrypted with TLS. However, when I receive a sensitive documents, I usually get a message with link stating "you have received encrypted email, click here to open it". Then a third party website opens after clicking the link. I don't understand what is the point of this. If my email service (Gmail in this case) supports TLS, why use this "external encryption service"?

Comment: By encrypting an email, the sender guarantees security by using a security method they trust, especially when the majority of users use insecure passwords in general, let alone for their email/SSO accounts, coupled with many using inherently insecure web-based email clients instead of a desktop client. Rather than risking the security unknowns, a sender has more control over the dissemination of sensitive information by sending it encrypted, which also prevents it from being viewed by any with access to the email account without decrypting it each time it's viewed.

Comment: @JW0914 But anyone having access to email account can still open and decrypt the message simply by clicking the link. I do understand what is the benefit of encryption but I do not understand what benefit there is to use external encryption service (like one provided by Microsoft) instead of traditional SSL/TLS? If someone has access to email account they can decrypt it anyway. Why is web-based client less secure than desktop client?

Comment: For a definitive answer to the specific sender, it would be better to ask the sender to ascertain their reasoning _(SSL certs are just one way to encrypt, with many using GPG to encrypt files)_. Web-based email clients allow malicious code/files to show and execute at substantially higher rates than desktop clients, which almost always catch such emails and their content, sandboxing them in junk/spam, allowing the email to only be shown in plain text _(a more thorough answer can be found by using google, which will also explain how the browser itself also creates a security issue)_

Comment: @JW0914 Yeah well thanks for your answer. I'm a software developer myself but this something I have never really understood. From every technical point of view, there seems to be no reason to use external encryption if both sender and receiver emails support TLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But anyone having access to email account can still open and decrypt the message simply by clicking the link.

It is possible that the sender can track when the link was opened and from which device. If it was just a regular attachment, they couldn't know if someone in another country reads all your emails – but they will know when that someone clicks on the link, and be alerted about leaks that way.

Additionally, it is possible that the sender can deactivate the link at any time. They cannot unsend a message because it's on *your* inbox already, but they can take down the documents because those are still on *their* system.

Other reasons:

1. TLS for websites usually goes all the way from the browser to the server. If there are any non-TLS hops, they're on the server side, so under control of the "sender".

   This is not the case with email. Even though the sender knows that TLS is usable for delivery to the *first* server, it doesn't know what happens afterwards. Once accepted, the message might go through a few more servers (load balancers, spam filters, antivirus scanners) – all those things happen at the recipient's side.

   Most importantly, even if the SMTP delivery to your inbox is TLS-secured all the way, that still doesn't mean if the pickup using IMAP or POP3 iš secured as well. If you use a dedicated mail app and it's accidentally configured to use plaintext IMAP, the sender won't know that, and you won't realize it either.
2. When you're accessing an HTTPS website, the browser is strict in verifying the certificate, enforcing secure ciphers, etc. Email unfortunately can't do that for SMTP delivery from one domain to another, as many recipients will have mismanaged SMTP servers with expired certificates and such.
3. It is possible that the service allows hosting larger files than what your (or the sender's) mail server accepts. For example, there are still corporate mail systems which only accept 1–2 MB but you just have to send that 50 MB bundle of documents...

Comment: So you are saying that's because the sender doesn't trust that receiver's email server is properly configured for TLS? This is probably not a problem with larger email providers such as Gmail, Outlook etc. but it might be a concern with corporate email. Alright thanks.

Comment: Not only that, but they might distrust it for reasons _other than TLS._ Gmail is still subject to legal requests, for example.

Comment: @Curious Be aware, even corporate might like Microsoft has been known to [fail to renew a domain or an SSL certificate](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/02/yesterdays-multi-hour-teams-outage-was-due-to-an-expired-ssl-certificate/) :)